# Data preparation for association rules algorithm (apriori)

Tags: python, sql, dataframe

I need help with my data preparation for a project I am working on.
I have 2 columns csv file, one contains the Order number, the second contains the items purchased.

Here's a sample of what I have:

```
1 A
1 B
1 C
2 A 
2 D 
3 F
3 G
3 K
```

I need to transform it to:

```
1 A B C
2 A D
3 F G K
```

(this is just a sample I made.. I have 70k rows)
Any help would be amazing. SQL / Python / excel are the tools I know how to work with. So if it possible, the answer within one of them would be the best.
Thanks!

Comment: If SQL, which dbms are you using?

Comment: I can use either SQL server or Jupyter (Ptyhon 3) notebook for the workflow

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY NUMBER ORDER BY LETTER)` (inner query), then using sub queries you can select the letters as columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is spectacularly simple with Python and `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections
order_to_products = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('input.csv') as inp:
   for l in inp:
      order_id, *products = l.split()
      order_to_products[order_id].extend(products)
for order_id, products in order_to_products.items():
   print(order_id, ' '.join(products))
```

(As an added bonus, this actually supports input lines with multiple products.)

E.g.

```
$ cat > input.csv
1 A
1 B
1 C
2 A
2 D
3 F
3 G
3 K
$ python3
>>> import collections
>>> order_to_products = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> with open('input.csv') as inp:
...    for l in inp:
...       order_id, *products = l.split()
...       order_to_products[order_id].extend(products)
...
>>> for order_id, products in order_to_products.items():
...    print(order_id, ' '.join(products))
...
1 A B C
2 A D
3 F G K
```

Comment: @YoavBarzilai It gives me the exact expected output; I edited in a run log.

Comment: Hey and thanks for the quick reply, but this is what I get as output for your script: "defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'ן»¿basket,item_code': [], '1890,535': [], '1890,527': [], '1890,593': [], '1890,569': [], '1890,503': [], '1890,501': [], '1890,1': [], '1891,8.41E+12': [], '1891,7.29E+12': [], '1891,1': [], '1891,565': [], '1891,569': [], '1891,571': [], '1892,529': [],"

Comment: Obviously your data is not space separated, then, as you implied in your original post. Use `l.split(',')` instead of `l.split()` to split by commas. Also, judging by that `8.41E+12`, the data is already corrupt (long numbers have been turned into scientific notation).

Comment: Thanks man, really helped me. now I have a txt file which contained the list of lists I needed. (every list is an order and the attributes seperated with ','). do you know how I put it as rows in a pandas dataframe? (every row suppose to be an order and every cell is number(product).?

Comment: @YoavBarzilai That's another question, but https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html will help.